# is Dialog class having a method equivalent to OnConfigurationChanged()?

Tags: android, dialog

I have many custom dialogs with list view in my droid app and there are plenty of cropping issues while rotating. I have solved these kinds of issues in classes which extend Activity with the help of onConfigurationChanged() method. Is there any equivalent method in Dialog class?

Comment: Please be more specific about the issues you're facing and how you worked them arround.